# WampServer - MySQL service doesn't start

Tags: mysql, wamp

I cannot use WAMP properly as MySQL service is not starting neither when I click on wampserver/mysql/StartResume Service.

Please note:

1. WampServer icon is orange
2. I can use MySQL console and see all of my databases
3. PhpMyAdmin works when I browse on http://localhost/phpmyadmin
4. **innodb_additional_mem_pool_size** is not in **my.ini**
5. Mysql.log is empty**strong text**
6. **innodb_force_recovery = 1** does not change anything

What else shall I try?

I am new to WAMP.

Here is **my.ini**:

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:\mysql\data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data

lc-messages-dir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/share

#innodb_force_recovery = 1


# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR

# Avoid warning
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)


# New for MySQL 5.6 if no slave
skip-slave-start

#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port=3306
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
```

Comment: By any chance, do you have Skype installed on your machine and is your Apache server working?

Comment: What is the exact error message what you are getting?

Comment: What is the content of `c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log`?

Comment: I have skype4business, mysql.log is empty. @SathishD, where shall I check the error message?

Comment: It should be in `c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log`

Comment: @julestruong, thanks but mysql.log is empty

Comment: The reason I am asking is because the Skype port number conflicts with the Apache Server as they both use the same port.

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif, thanks but Apache Server is up

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif SKYPE does not conflict with the MYSQL port which is 3306. It can conflict with Apache i.e. port 80.

Comment: Apologies, I assumed it was all ONE... learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif No problem, on a good day I Iearn more than one new thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your question you say :-

- I can use MySQL console and see all of my databases*
- PhpMyAdmin works when I browse on http://localhost/phpmyadmin*

In that case MySQL **must be running**

So that makes me think that you have got a second MySQL Server running on your system.

MySQL can be installed as part of some other tools/apps. If that is the case they normally set the service name to `MYSQL` and set it to start `automatically` so it is probably running before you get to start WAMPServer and therefore blocking port 3306. The WAMPServer MySQL instance is called `wampmysqld` (or `wampmysqld64` if you run the 64bit WAMPSever). Have a look at what services are running using the `services.msc` snapin.

```
WINDOWS KEY + R
enter services.msc
Press the OK button
```

You only need one MYSQL Server to serve many databases, so you need to decide which one you want to use. If you decide to remove the non WAMPServer MySQL then **dont forget to backup your databases before removing the old MySQL**

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue with my new Wamp 3.1.9 installation. Somehow the `data` dir was missing in `mysql5.7.26`. A quick fix was to run this command from `bin` dir: `mysqld --initialize-insecure`

Comment: Note that it's the mysql's bin and not wamp's

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was other multiple instances of MySQL. I have installed MySQL Workbench from Oracle. Turns out I could only have one MySQL service running at a time.

Comment: I had same problem with WAMP. Trouble is/was Mysql workbench launches before WAMP and 'took' PORT 3306.  SO wamp just sat there all orange.   I removed the mysql notifier ( which lost me 5 hours)  .    Is there a way to make wamp be the default connection?. At the moment , every time i have a windows update and it closes the connection i have to mess around switiching mysql57  off before wamp will launch.

Answer (score 1):

This solution helped me:

1. Tray Wamp icon (left click) ->  MySQL -> Service administration -> Remove service
2. exit Wamp: Wamp icon (right click) -> exit
3. run Wamp again and restart All service

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did some research online and it mentioned that you need to do the following:

**Search for mysql-bin.index file, delete it, then restart MySQL**

Comment: where is this file supposed to be?

Comment: wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data directory

Answer (score 0):

1. Tray Wamp icon (left click) -> MySQL -> Service administration -> Remove service
2. exit Wamp: Wamp icon (right click) -> exit
3. run Wamp again
4. Install MYSQL Service
5. restart All service

This works for me